# Bigquery - how do i select the fields that are in my where clause and not constants?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery and fairly early in my SQL journey too. 
I have a SQL query of which the objective is to bring back the total visits recorded for that particular country of a particular domain.
The country is determined by a combination of specifying a the hits.customDimensions.index and hits.customDimensions.value as well as the page host
I want to be able to bring back the total visits by country. However my code below gives my completely inflated numbers for every country. Can anyone help me with my dodgy aggregation?

```
SELECT
date,
hits.customDimensions.index,
hits.customDimensions.value,
SUM(totals.visits) AS totals_visits

FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([95212100.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))

WHERE
hits.page.hostname = 'www.xxxx.com' AND ((hits.customDimensions.index=5
AND hits.customDimensions.value='US') OR (hits.customDimensions.index=5
AND hits.customDimensions.value='UK') OR ((hits.customDimensions.index=5
AND hits.customDimensions.value='India')))

GROUP BY date, hits.customDimensions.index, hits.customDimensions.value
```

Comment: The query looks OK, the only reason why totals_visits would be inflated, if you had multiple hits.customDimensions for every visit - then it will be counted multiple times by this query.

Comment: Excellent explanation - thenk you. I realise that i was mixing granularities of the data here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  date, val, SUM(visits) AS visits
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    totals.visits AS visits, 
    l.value AS val,
    MAX(hits.customDimensions.index = 5 
        AND hits.customDimensions.value = l.value
      ) WITHIN RECORD AS flag
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([95212100.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))) AS s
  CROSS JOIN ( -- Pre-Selected Countries Only
     SELECT value FROM 
      (SELECT 'US' as value), 
      (SELECT 'UK' as value), 
      (SELECT 'India' as value)
  ) AS l
  WHERE hits.page.hostname = 'www.xxxx.com' 
  AND hits.customDimensions.index = 5 
  HAVING flag
)
GROUP BY date, val
```

If you would need to output all countries - you can use below query

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  date, val, SUM(visits) AS visits
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    totals.visits AS visits, 
    l.value AS val,
    MAX(hits.customDimensions.index = 5 
        AND hits.customDimensions.value = l.value
      ) WITHIN RECORD AS flag
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([95212100.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))) AS s
  CROSS JOIN ( -- All 'qualified' countries 
    SELECT hits.customDimensions.value AS value
    FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([95212100.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))
    WHERE hits.page.hostname = 'www.xxxx.com' 
    AND hits.customDimensions.index = 5 
    GROUP BY value
  ) AS l
  WHERE hits.page.hostname = 'www.xxxx.com' 
  AND hits.customDimensions.index = 5 
  HAVING flag
)
GROUP BY date, val
```